# saving the complete url string containing multiple parameters in php

Tags: php

I am passing multiple parameters to a webpage successfully.
On the receiving page, I would like to save the complete url string in a database or in a file, for the purpose of resubmitting it if something failed.
I am saving one parameter at the time, but I do not know how to save the complete url string without manipulating it.
Below is the string to save as an example.
Thank you for your input,
George

`http://sample.net/send.php?macid='5c:cf:7f:01:32:0b:'&a1='0.00'&a2='9999.00'&a3='9999.00'&a4='15.00'&datesaved=''&power='0'&baro='0.0'&pushbutton='5'&button='5'&pump='1'&pump2='1'&pump3='1'&pump4='1'&signal='62'&temp1='20.00'&temp2='23.40'&temp3='0.00'&freq='20'&rebootfreq='864000'&clientcode=''&ip='xxx'&reboottimes='2'`

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php

Answer (score 1):

```
$url_string = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$file = 'file.txt';
file_put_contents($file, $url_string);
```

to read it

```
 echo file_get_contents('file.txt');
```

you can also use [fopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) to get more flexible access to the file e.g rewrite or append etc

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer.

Comment: Hi Amr,I was using the same code in 2 different webpages, but got different answers depending of how I was sending the info. When it is sent thru a get, I have the following string and the url is repeated twice like: http://GET http://api....http://api.

Comment: http://GET http://xxxx/send.php?macid=''&a1='13.06'&a2='2.39'&a3='0.00'&a4='2.23'&signal='62'&pump='1'&temp1='25.40'&temp2='0.00'&temp3='0.00'&freq='1774'&rebootfreq='864000'&clientcode=''&ip=''&reboottimes='2'http://xxxx/send.php?macid=''&a1='13.06'&a2='2.39'&a3='0.00'&a4='2.23'&datesaved=''&power='0'&baro=''&pushbutton='5'&button='5'&pump='1'&pump2='1'&pump3='1'&pump4='1'&signal='62'&temp1='25.40'&temp2='n/a'&temp3='0.00'&freq='1774'&rebootfreq='864000'&clientcode=''&ip=''&reboottimes='2','{"success":true,"errors":[],"token":"ac4625beb0"}',DB Updated,' '

Comment: I used $url_string = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; to solve the duplication.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my issue by using the following:
$url_string = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
Thanks to everyone help